# Call a method on a service created dynamically by a bundle

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection, yaml

I am using the `m6web_guzzle` bundle to register several http clients:

```
m6web_guzzlehttp:
    clients:
        myclient:
            timeout: 3
            headers:
                "Accept": "application/json"
            delay: 0
            verify: false
```

I want to call a method on a service that it dynamically generates. In this case the generated service name is:

```
@m6web_guzzlehttp.guzzle.handlerstack.myclient
```

Here is what I do in my service constructor: (the 3rd parameter injected is '@m6web_guzzlehttp.guzzle.handlerstack.myclient')

```
/**
 * @param array        $parameters
 * @param Client       $client
 * @param HandlerStack $handlerStack
 */
public function __construct(array $parameters, Client $client, HandlerStack $handlerStack)
{
    $this->parameters = $parameters;
    $this->client = $client;
    $this->handlerStack->push(Middleware::retry([$this, 'retryDecider']));
}
```

So far, it works well, but how can I transfer the last line (the `push` call) in my `services.yml` file? Or another cleaner method to register this retry handler?

Comment: You can write a [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#components-di-compiler-pass) that grabs the definition in question and adds the method call to it.

Answer (score 3):

In your bundle's `Extension.php` file, you can override the load method and add:

```
$definition = $container->getDefinition('m6web_guzzlehttp.guzzle.handlerstack.myclient');
$definition->addMethodCall('push', [Middleware::retry([$this, 'retryDecider'])]);
```

Comment: Hi, the m6web_guzzlehttp.guzzle.handlerstack.myclient service is not yet created when the load function is called. "You have requested a non-existent service..."

Comment: Probably the guzzle bundle is not loaded yet. Please add the order of bundle registration from AppKernel (registerBundles method) .I l take a look.

Comment: No, the bundle with this extension is in last position.

Comment: Are you sure the name of dynamically created service is `m6web_guzzlehttp.guzzle.handlerstack.myclient` and the service is infact  created during guzzle bundles registration. If its created, it's definition should be accessible from container builder in YourExtension.php

Answer (score 3):

So compiler passes were mentioned before. That is one option.

### Use factories to create instances

But you can *nearly* express this also directly in your services definition. I say *nearly*, because you will need some kind of code as Symfony service definitions cannot (AFAIK) evaluate to a Closure - which is what we need for the Guzzle Middleware.

I wrote up this services.yml as an example:

```
m6web_guzzlehttp.guzzle.handlerstack.myclient:
    class: GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack
    factory: ['GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack', create]

retry_decider:
    class: MyBundle\RetryDecider
    factory: ['MyBundle\RetryDecider', createInstance]

retry_handler:
    class: GuzzleHttp\Middleware
    factory: ['GuzzleHttp\Middleware', retry]
    arguments:
        - '@retry_decider'

handlerstack_pushed:
    parent: m6web_guzzlehttp.guzzle.handlerstack.myclient
    calls:
        - [push, ['@retry_handler']]
```

### What is what?

- `m6web_guzzlehttp.guzzle.handlerstack.myclient` - Your dynamic service - remove from example as you have this already created.
- `retry_decider` - Your decider. We return a Closure in the `createInstance` method. You can add more parameters if you need, just add arguments to your YML.
- `retry_handler` - Here we compose the middleware using our decider
- `handlerstack_pushed` - Here we `push()` our handler into the stack, using the dynamic service as a parent service.

Et voilà - we have the stack that the dynamic service defined, but pushed our retry middleware.

Here is the source for our decider:

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle;

class RetryDecider {

    public static function createInstance() {
        return function() {
            // do your deciding here
        };
    }

}
```

--> You now have the service `handlerstack_pushed` which is the complete Stack.

### Configuring more

Please note that you could add `m6web_guzzlehttp.guzzle.handlerstack.myclient` to `parameters.yml`:

```
parameters:
    baseHandlerStackService: m6web_guzzlehttp.guzzle.handlerstack.myclient
```

Then use that on `handlerstack_pushed`:

```
handlerstack_pushed:
    parent: "%baseHandlerStackService%"
    calls:
        - [push, ['@retry_handler']]
```

Just nicer like that ;-)

Comment: I havn't any error in the services.yml but the Retrydecider is never called.

Comment: @COil well, did you pass the "handlerstack_pushed" service to any other service that is in use? if you don't connect that to anything that is in use (I don't know what you're doing with that), it will not be called..

Comment: Well I don't know how this service "lives" as it is created automatically by the bundle. But no I don't pass it manually to other services. It seems it is the same error mentioned in @asha answer, it may be overwritten later in the process. I must investigate further. Not so easy.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#components-di-compiler-pass) that grabs the definition in question and adds the method call to it.

Comment: I was expecting an example. :)

Comment: Can you point to the code that creates this dynamic service so that I can look into how you could solve that concrete problem with a compiler pass (I'll update my answer then)?

Comment: More details added.

Comment: I have added the code, but the decider function is not called. If I call the same code from the controller it works.

Comment: The pushed stack seems to be overwritten later in the process. When creating it in the extension it is at position 5, and when creating manually in a controller it is in last as position 7.